# White gaps in Chrome DevTools flame chart

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, profiling

Profiling a function call, the high-level events are represented as uninterrupted orange lines. But function calls made by the high-level events may be disjointed by white gaps, making it look like multiple calls even if it is only called once.

What does these white gaps represent, and is there a way to display all calls as uninterrupted lines, just like the high-level events?

**Figure 15 from [Chrome DevTools - Performance Analysis Reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference#main)**

[image: Figure 15 from Chrome DevTools Performance Analysis Reference]

In the figure, the white gap splits the calls represented with light-green (*(anonymous)*, *Me*, *Se*, etc) into two parts even it it is a single call.

Comment: Is just a bug/quirk in Chrome. It tries its best to coalesce CPU samples but sometimes fails.

Comment: I'm observing the same behaviour. Have you found a way around this?

Comment: @Spiff No, I am afraid not. wOxxOmMar's comment is my best guess as of why.

Comment: @ANisus Disabling "High resolution CPU profiling" in the DevTools settings seems to solve this.